# Create a new column in df based on multiple NaN checks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I am trying to create a derived column based on multiple NaN checks.

Df

```
A|B|C
NaN|23|dfs
NaN|NaN|dsdfs
1223|3423|234234
NaN|NaN|NaN
```

Df with derived field
D - if A and B and C is not empty or NaN, concatenate the values in A,B,C

```
A|B|C|D
NaN|23|dfs|""
NaN|NaN|dsdfs|""
1223|3423|234234|12233423234234
NaN|NaN|NaN|""
```

i tried the code below

```
df["D"] = np.where(df["A"].notna() and df["B"].notna() and df["C"].notna(), df["A"].map(str)+df["B"].map(str) + df["C"].map(str), "")
```

Error i got was
Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

any help is appreciated!
thank you!

Comment: The error comes from `and`. Use `&` instead. `df["A"].notna() & df["B"].notna() & df["C"].notna()`. (See. [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing))

Comment: Thank you! it solved my error. May i know when should i use "&" and "and"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
# df = df.convert_dtypes() uncomment this to convert dtypes of all the columns to suitable data-types. 
(
    df.assign(D=np.where(
        df.isna().any(axis=1),
        "",
        df.astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1) # or df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)
    )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following. Simple explanation would be using `np.where` where checking condition if columns `A,B,C` anyone of them is null then keep new column's value to empty else take sum of 3 of the columns and assign it to new column named `D`.

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
df['D'] = np.where(df[cols].isnull().any(1),'',df[cols].astype(str).sum(1))
```

Comment: @yuzu, Could you please do let me know if this solution has worked for you?